# How to do RFE form caret using xgboost?

Tags: r, matrix, xgboost, r-caret, rfe

I am trying to use the recursive feature elimination method using "xgbtree" as method.
However I always encounter some error.

This is my code:

```
control <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs,
                      method = "repeatedcv", # repeated cv
                      repeats = 5, # number of repeats
                      number = 10) # number of folds

result_rfe1 <- rfe(x_train, y_train,
                   sizes = c(1:9),
                   rfeControl = control,
                   method="xgbTree")
```

If I use:

```
x_train <- data.matrix(x_train)
x_train <- xgb.DMatrix(x_train),
```

I have the error Error in { : task 1 failed - "unused argument (drop = FALSE)" and I have already downgraded the caret package and it did not work.

If I don't use xgb.DMatrix and use this:

```
x_train <- x[ inTrain, ],
```

the code runs but this is the output:
Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
RMSE        Rsquared        MAE
Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA
1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA
Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA
Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN
3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA
Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA
NA's   :108   NA's   :108   NA's   :108

I do have some factor variballes, but I have tried to do the same RFE with random forest and it was not a problem. Any ideas on what can be wrong?

I already tried to downgrade the caret package but it did not work.